# ¿Cómo reemplazar una linea especifica de un archivo txt en python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

llevo bastante tratando de averiguar como reemplazar una linea de texto especifica de un archivo por otra, Cuando obtengo un mejor tiempo.
(El txt es creado por el mismo programa y siempre varian los datos)
Saludos.

```
                stats="Jugador: " +str(nombre)+" con"+str(Movimientos_hechos)+" jugadas"+" en " +str(tiempo)+" Segundos.\n"
                leer=open("estadisticas.txt","r")
                comprobacion1=leer.readlines()
                print("Lineaaaaaaa",comprobacion1[1])
                linea=str(comprobacion1[1])
                aca=linea.split(" ")
                numero_real=float(aca[6])
                print(tiempo)
                print(numero_real)
                leer.close()
                if numero_real>float(tiempo):                       
                    reem=open("estadisticas.txt","r")
                    it=(lina for i,lina in enumerate(reem) if i==1)
```

[image: Linea de codigo]

[image: Archivo creado]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Deberias añadir el código como texto en lugar de poner imágenes ya que facilita la tarea a quien quiera ayudarte. Te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: Puedes usar el módulo `os`, que básicamente lo que hace es que te permite poner un comando en la terminal desde python, entonces puedes limpiar la pantalla `os.system('clear')` (creo que en mac también es bash) desde python y después imprimir todo lo que estaba escrito pero con el texto cambiado

Comment: @ElPasta no necesito limpiar la pantalla, sino cambiar la linea especifica del txt con el nuevo mejor tiempo conseguido.

Comment: @Flicks disculpa, en ese puedes caso usar `open(archivo,"w")` para escribir en el archivo, pero este se te sobreescribirá, por lo que anteriormente abras tenido que [guardar el archivo](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) en una lista y simplemente reemplazar en la lista la linea que te gustaria poner.

Answer (score 3):

Aquí te dejo la manera fácil de reemplazar lineas especificas en python.

```
contenido = file("ARCHIVO.txt").read().splitlines()
contenido.insert(LINEA,TEXTO)
f = file("ARCHIVO.txt", "w")
f.writelines("\n".join(contenido))
```

No entendí muy bien como funciona tu código... Pero estoy seguro que sera fácil funcionar tu código con este.